# sequencing data using hive functions

Tags: hive

I have a hive table

```
create table abc ( id int, channel string, time int ); 

insert into table abc values
(1,'a', 12),
(1,'c', 10),
(1,'b', 15),
(2,'a', 15),
(2,'c', 12),
(2,'c', 7);
```

I want resultant table to look something like this -

```
id , journey
1, c->a->b
2, c->c->a
```

`journey` column is arranged in ascending order by time per `id`

I have tried

```
select id , concat_ws(">", collect_list(channel)) as journey
from abc 
group by id
```

but it does not preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery and order by time(to preserve order) then in the outer query use collect_list with group by clause.

```
hive> select id , concat_ws("->", collect_list(channel)) as journey from 
      ( 
        select * from abc order by time
       )t 
        group by id;
    +-----+----------------+--+
    | id  |    journey     |
    +-----+----------------+--+
    | 1   | 'c'->'a'->'b'  |
    | 2   | 'c'->'c'->'a'  |
    +-----+----------------+--+
```

Comment: what is the cost of order operation in subquery if my data is more than 10Million records?

Comment: @Regressor, As we are using **`Order By`** clause that means only **one reducer** is going to do all the work as a result we are not going to get `any parallelism` and please do load test on your end by running the query on your dataset.